# Percentage with Jquery and write in multiples divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning JS and I have a question about a specific situation. I am trying to calculate % and write in the div `#porc` using JS. My question is how to make this function better and how to work with multiple divs with same class.

The HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="precoCheio">400,00</div>
  <div class="precoDesc">150,00</div>
  <div id="porc"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="precoCheio">200,00</div>
  <div class="precoDesc">150,00</div>
  <div id="porc"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="precoCheio">1000,00</div>
  <div class="precoDesc">600,00</div>
  <div id="porc"></div>
</div>
```

The JS

```
function calculaPorcentagem(){
     var precoCheio = $(".wrapper .precoCheio").text();
     var precoDesc = $(".precoDesc").text();

     precoCheio    = precoCheio.replace(".", "");
     precoCheio    = precoCheio.replace(",", ".");
     precoDesc    = precoDesc.replace(".", "");
     precoDesc    = precoDesc.replace(",", ".");
     precoDesc    = precoDesc.replace(".", "");
     precoDesc    = precoDesc.replace(",", ".");


     var porcentagem = precoDesc * 100 / precoCheio / 100;
     var porcentagem = porcentagem.toFixed(0) - 100;

     $('#porc').html(porcentagem + ' % OFF ');

      var val = $("#porc").html();
      $("#porc").html(val.substring(1, val.length));
};
```

Comment: ids should be unique

Comment: I am just making a example and I ctrl C / ctrl V the elements.

Comment: Why is this code in Portuguese if this is just an example? Anyway, if you are new to JavaScript, try to remember to *always coerce numerical texts into number before doing calculations*. It'll help you avoid a lot of trouble in the future.

Comment: Perhaps because I am from Brazil, genious ;) hah. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
// run on document ready
$(function() {
  // cycle through each wrapper
  $('.wrapper').each(function() {
    var wrapper = $(this), // get current wrapper
        cheio = wrapper.children('.precoCheio'), // get child 'precoCheio' of current wrapper
        cheioVal = parseFloat(cheio.text().replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".")), // replace ALL dots then change first comma to dot
        desc = wrapper.children('.precoDesc'),  // get child 'precoDesc' of current wrapper
        descVal = parseFloat(desc.text().replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", ".")),
        porc = wrapper.children('.porc'); // get child 'porc' of current wrapper
  
    
    // do your calculation
    var porcentagem = 100 - ((descVal / cheioVal) * 100);

    // put result into current porc
    porc.html(porcentagem + ' % OFF');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="precoCheio">400,00</div>
  <div class="precoDesc">150,00</div>
  <div class="porc"></div>
</div><br />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="precoCheio">200,00</div>
  <div class="precoDesc">150,00</div>
  <div class="porc"></div>
</div><br />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="precoCheio">1000,00</div>
  <div class="precoDesc">600,00</div>
  <div class="porc"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: have added a few more comments to help out

Comment: @Geo Basically: for each element that matches `.wrapper`, he gets the text, coerces it into numbers, calculates the percentage and writes it into the elements that match `.porc` / Basicamente: pra cada elemento econtrado por `.wrapper`, ele pega os textos, força a leitura em números, calcula a porcentagem e escreve dentro dos elementos `.porc`. (sorry, I figured he'd have a hard time reading in ENG so I've explained it in two languages)

Comment: @Pete help me with this doubt please :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33109706/transforming-select-in-radio-button-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

In addition

$.fn.html can accept functions too. Like this

```
function calculaPorcentagem(){
     var $wrapper = $(this).parrent();
     var precoCheio = $wrapper.find(".precoCheio").text();
     var precoDesc = $wrapper.find(".precoDesc").text();
 //here some your logic 
     precoCheio    = precoCheio.replace(".", "");
     precoCheio    = precoCheio.replace(",", ".");
     precoDesc    = precoDesc.replace(".", "");
     precoDesc    = precoDesc.replace(",", ".");
     precoDesc    = precoDesc.replace(".", "");
     precoDesc    = precoDesc.replace(",", ".");

     var porcentagem = precoDesc * 100 / precoCheio / 100;
     var porcentagem = porcentagem.toFixed(0) - 100;
        return porcentagem + ' % OFF';
    };

    $('.porc').html(calculaPorcentagem);
```