# Transforming: Select in Radio button using Jquery

Tags: jquery, select, radio-button

I have two select elemments (first is size, second is color). I am having trouble to make two adjusts in this code and I need help to understand how proceed.

First: 
I am using a class called 'checked' when I select a option (radio button). However the problem is I need keep the class 'checked' in the first option (size) when I select the second option (color).

Second:
The user cannot select the second option (color) without select the size first (first option). So I need disable the color option until the user select a size.

HTML

```
<select name="iluria-product-variation1" id="iluria-product-variation1" onchange="selectedVariation1()">
<option value="0" id="default-variation-1" selected="selected">Tamanho</option>
<option value="2DE650" class="variation1-option">PP</option>
<option value="2DE651" class="variation1-option">P</option>
<option value="2DE652" class="variation1-option">M</option>
<option value="2DE653" class="variation1-option">G</option>
<option value="2DE654" class="variation1-option">GG</option></select>

<select name="iluria-product-variation2" id="iluria-product-variation2" onchange="selectedVariation2()">
<option value="0" id="default-variation-2" selected="selected">Cor</option>
<option value="2DE655" class="variation2-option">Amarelo</option>
<option value="2DE661" class="variation2-option">Vinho</option>
<option value="2DE660" class="variation2-option">Vermelho</option>
<option value="2DE65F" class="variation2-option">Verde</option>
<option value="2DE65E" class="variation2-option">Roxo</option>
<option value="2DE65D" class="variation2-option">Rosa</option>
<option value="2DE65C" class="variation2-option">Preto</option>
<option value="2DE65B" class="variation2-option">Marrom</option>
<option value="2DE65A" class="variation2-option">Laranja</option>
<option value="2DE659" class="variation2-option">Dourado</option>
<option value="2DE658" class="variation2-option">Cinza</option>
<option value="2DE657" class="variation2-option">Branco</option>
<option value="2DE656" class="variation2-option">Azul</option>
<option value="2DE662" class="variation2-option">Violeta</option>
```

The JS

```
$('select#iluria-product-variation1, select#iluria-product-variation2').each(function(i, select){
var $select = jQuery(select);
$select.find('option').each(function(j, option){
var $option = jQuery(option);
// Create a radio:
var $radio = jQuery('<input type="radio" />');
// Set name and value:
$radio.attr('name', $select.attr('name')).attr('value', $option.val()).attr('id', $option.text());
// Set checked if the option was selected
if ($option.attr('selected')) $radio.attr('checked', 'checked');
// Insert radio before select box:
    $select.before($radio);
    $radio.wrap('<div class="vari-option fix" />');
// Insert a label:
$radio.before(
    $("<label />").attr('for', $option.text()).text($option.text()).addClass($option.text())
);
    $(".product-variations-container").css("display", "block");
});
}); 

$(':radio').click(function(){
$(this).parent().parent().find('label').removeClass('checked');
$(this).siblings('label').addClass('checked');
$choice = $(this).attr('value');
$('select#iluria-product-variation1 option[value=' + $choice + ']').attr('selected',true).parent().trigger('change');
$('select#iluria-product-variation2 option[value=' + $choice + ']').attr('selected',true).parent().trigger('change');
});
```

> Example on JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3kzmq12g/2/

Any help is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute selectors and the .on() method to acheive what you want to , basically you just need to add a on() listener to see if the first set of radio buttons are checked or not.

```
$('[name="iluria-product-variation2"]').prop('disabled', true); 

$(document).on('click' , 'input[name="iluria-product-variation1"]'  , function(){
    $('[name="iluria-product-variation2"]').prop('disabled', false) 
});

$('[name="iluria-product-variation2"]').click(function(){
    $('[name="iluria-product-variation2"]').siblings('label').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).siblings('label').addClass('checked');
    $choice = $(this).attr('value');
    $('select#iluria-product-variation1 option[value=' + $choice + ']').attr('selected',true).parent().trigger('change');
    $('select#iluria-product-variation2 option[value=' + $choice + ']').attr('selected',true).parent().trigger('change');
});

$('[name="iluria-product-variation1"]').click(function(){
    $('[name="iluria-product-variation1"]').siblings('label').removeClass('checked');
    $(this).siblings('label').addClass('checked');
    $choice = $(this).attr('value');
    $('select#iluria-product-variation1 option[value=' + $choice + ']').attr('selected',true).parent().trigger('change');
    $('select#iluria-product-variation2 option[value=' + $choice + ']').attr('selected',true).parent().trigger('change');
});

$('select#iluria-product-variation1').on('change' , function(){
    $('[name="iluria-product-variation2"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/3kzmq12g/5/)**

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I've tried a lot of ways to make the code looks better, but I have failed. I just forgot to mention in my example, when the user change the size, the second select (color) should be disable (again). Really thanks for your help.

Comment: @Geo edited my answer ! press the accept answer button , if this is what you were looking for ;) , its the tick mark !

Comment: I could kiss you. Thanks a lot, I will try understand what you did.

Comment: @Geo , this code can be shortened to something much more shorter , i'll refactor it when i have the time , thats the beauty of jQuery , often whats written in 10-20 lines of code can be shortened to 2-3 line of code ... thats the beauty of jQuery , remember that . chao :)